# How to set primary key of the Sqlite3 table when using to_sql?

Tags: sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy, pandas-to-sql

I have DataFrame that is needed to save as a table. I used this one and it works well.

```
result.to_sql(
    'tbl_name',
    index_label='date',
    dtype={'date': Date},
    con=engine.connect(), if_exists='append', index = True
)
```

The difficult problem is that I can not find a way to set `Primary Key` for the table. I need to define `date`(Date) and `symbol`(String) as `Primary Key`. As it is impossible to set primary key for `sqlite3` after creation, I think there must be a way to set primary key when using `to_sql`, but could not find. Can anybody help me?

Thank you.

Comment: New to SQLite myself, but think you have to create a temporary table (with your primary keys defined), copy the data to the temp table, drop the old table, then rename the temp table.

Comment: Maybe. But I want to use create tables dynamically so that it can save the history data properly.